# Reduce Bandwidth usage in cURL PHP

Tags: php, curl, gzip, libcurl, php-curl

I'm using basic cURL requests to fetch webpages in PHP, however these webpages are big in size and I'm limited in bandwidth usage.

Is there a way to reduce/optimize cURL data usage, for example using compression. I also heard that Brotli compression is the best, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$headers[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip"; // tell the server you accept gzip
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip"); // tells curl to gunzip it automatically
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Not tried this with brotli, support will vary by software version which you didn't tell us about.

Comment: Do you have an estimate percentage of bandwidth that gzip could save me? Also I'm using Apache...

Comment: No - because it depends on your content. For 7-bit natural language, I would expect in the region of 70-90% reduction. Gif, png and jpg data is already highly compressed and gzipping will make them slightly larger (hence a correctly configured webserver won't attempt to compress these).

Comment: Hmm I see, is there a way to determine how much bandwidth cURL uses (in PHP) to test the difference?